# How can I center individual images within their own background boxes?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, jsx

I'm a beginner coder creating a dice rolling application with react, and I've encountered a css issue that's taking me far too long to figure out. Basically, I have a row of 6 dice, and I'd like each die to sit within a background box that will change color upon react state change. I have the react aspect down, but I can't get the background boxes to sit correctly.

I'm no CSS expert, and I'm building this to gain experience with react/redux, not css, so I'm a bit flustered by how long this is taking. Any explanation of why my current code isn't working would be greatly appreciated, as there are major gaps in my understanding of display: 'flex'.

Here's my code and a screenshot of the issue:

```
#css
.diceContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  padding:3vw;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

.diceContainer img {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 15px 0 0 15px;
  margin-right: .5px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px);
}

.dice_background_active {
  background: linear-gradient(#5F8EC9,#2255BE) 0 0 / 80px 80px no-repeat;
}
```

```
#jsx
 <div className="diceContainer">
       
          <div className={this.state.oneSelected ? "dice_background" : "dice_background_active"}>
          <img onClick={this.handleOnClick.bind(this, 1)}  src="img1"
           
          /></div>

          <div className={this.state.twoSelected ? "dice_background" : "dice_background_active"}>
          <img onClick={this.handleOnClick.bind(this, 2)}  src="img2"
            
          /></div>

          <div className={this.state.threeSelected ? "dice_background" : "dice_background_active"}>
           <img onClick={this.handleOnClick.bind(this, 3)}  src="img3"
          /></div>

          <div className={this.state.fourSelected ? "dice_background" : "dice_background_active"}>
           <img onClick={this.handleOnClick.bind(this, 4)}  src="img4"
            /></div>

          <div className={this.state.fiveSelected ? "dice_background" : "dice_background_active"}>
           <img onClick={this.handleOnClick.bind(this, 5)}  src="img5"
            /></div>

          <div className={this.state.sixSelected ? "dice_background" : "dice_background_active"}>
           <img onClick={this.handleOnClick.bind(this, 6)}  src="img6"
            />
            
        </div>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You're missing justify-content: 'center'; in .dice_background_active. ANd you probably don't need float if you're using flexbox

Comment: You've flexed all 6 die into a single row dice container, versus two dice containers. The  `float` rule is taking the dice out of relative positioning. Maybe use one class to style the dice, and a separate additional active class to override what is different for being active, seems mostly just the background color. Having both those classes is largely duplicate CSS and isn't very **DRY**.

Comment: you could  use a  background gradient and background-size from a single img container : here is the idea : https://jsfiddle.net/kv93repo/1  Beside, css value do not use quotes => typo here `display: 'flex';` in your plain CSS code.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I like the way that looks, but the background box still isnt aligned with the dice inside. Any idea how to remedy that?

Comment: for the background alignment, you have background-size,background-position, and padding to tweek its offset position., play with the code :) here litlle different : https://jsfiddle.net/16dmzyta/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple fix.

```
.diceContainer img {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 15px 0 0 15px;
  margin-right: .5px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px);
}
```

the way the padding is configured here is what's causing the off-centered appearance. i simply changed it to

```
 padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
```

[image]

thanks to @G-Cyrillus, @Drew Reese and @Shanie for pushing me in the right direction.